Linux server group permissions
I have an Ubuntu 24 server.
I have managed to create an Active Directory authentication using SSSD.
The users that logged in via AD automatically get added to the group graylog-cert-editor, and get their home folder created.
I want to restrict the graylog-cert-editor group access, so they'll have the following permissions:

rwx: /etc/graylog/certs/
rwx: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/
rwx: /home/their own folder
rwx: /home/ftpuser/

They should not be able to access any other folders of files.
I have tried the following methods:
- setfacl -R -m group:graylog-cert-editor:rwx /home/
- setfacl -R -m group:graylog-cert-editor:rwx /home/ftpuser/
- setfacl -R -m group:graylog-cert-editor:rwx /etc/graylog/certs/
- setfacl -R -m group:graylog-cert-editor:rwx /etc/elasticsearch/certs/
- setfacl -R -m group:graylog-cert-editor:--- /
- setfacl -R -m group:graylog-cert-editor:r-- / 
- setfacl -R -m group:graylog-cert-editor:r-- /etc/passwd
- setfacl -R -m group:graylog-cert-editor:r-- /etc/shadow
- setfacl -R -m group:graylog-cert-editor:r-- /etc/group
- setfacl -m group:graylog-cert-editor:--x /bin
- setfacl -m group:graylog-cert-editor:--x /usr
- setfacl -m group:graylog-cert-editor:--x /lib
- setfacl -m group:graylog-cert-editor:--x /lib64
- setfacl -m group:graylog-cert-editor:--x /var
- setfacl -m g:graylog-cert-editor:--x /run
- setfacl -m g:graylog-cert-editor:--x /dev
- chmod 755 /bin/bash
- setfacl -m g:graylog-cert-editor:--x /bin
- setfacl -m g:graylog-cert-editor:--x /etc
- setfacl -m g:graylog-cert-editor:--x /bin/bash
- chmod 1777 /dev/pts
- setfacl -m g:graylog-cert-editor:--x /dev/pts
- chmod 666 /dev/tty

The user can log in, the motd appears, then get the following error:
/bin/bash: Permission denied
Connection to <<SERVER_IP>> closed.
Any idea why is that?
Also:
How can I set the permissions automatically for the new AD users for their own home folder?
